# How to select a table between a TNS connection and a Direct one?

Tags: oracle, dblink, tns

I'm new in this forum, but I've seen a lot of inputs from different collaborators, & I would like to ask the following:

I've two databases (Oracle):

a) One with TNS names: `FVIDAL1@DVDATABASE.ORG.COM`.
A query into this one would be, for example (this works):

```
SELECT * FROM DVSCHEMA.TABLE1@DVDATABASE.ORG.COM;
```

b) The other has a direct connection (Host, Port & Service_Name): `FVIDAL1@DV.XXXXX.XX-XXXX-X.XXX.XXXXX.COM:Port/Service_Name`

I'm trying basically the same thing:

```
SELECT * FROM DVSCHEMA.TABLE1@DV.XXXXX.XX-XXXX-X.XXX.XXXXX.COM:Port/Service_Name
```

I'm not sure how I can connect to the second database from the first. So far I've been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a link with the connection specification and use that link

Comment: I tried that, but may be I did it wrongly, as I never could. At the end, I found the "Insufficient Privileges" error, so I gave up. But many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not selecting from TNS names entry, but from a database link. Which has just the same name. But practically it is a different object.

Comment: No, but the first database link is for a db that uses TNS Names, & the other is for one that requires "Direct" connection.